# Conditional DataElementName in SSRS RDL

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdl

Dear friends at stackoverflow,

I have a strange issue where I need to change DataElementName property of a textbox in RDL conditionally based on report parameter.  This is important for CSV export.  As far as my knowledge goes, I assume DataElementName property turns into a header when report is rendered in CSV format.  But I cannot have a static value for this property.  it is unfortunate that Report designer does not allow an expression for DataElementName.  What are my options?

Thank you in advance.